# Angular 2 javascript <script> tag not showing

Tags: javascript, angular, tags

i have an html page with some: `<script>` tags
When the page get rendered those get lost.
How can i make them show?

Edit:
got it to work

```
ngOnInit() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js";
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
  }
```

the only problem is that create the element at the bottom of the page after the . How can i create it as a child of another element?

Comment: If you are referring to <script> tags inside angular components, then they are sanitized.

Comment: yeah, but i tried to bypass that (looked at various page) but didn't work

Comment: Why on earth would you even have to do this? Just include it in your index file..

Comment: cause i need it only for 1 component not for the entire project